# Java script detect popup blocker in IE11

Tags: javascript

how to check in javacript weather the  internet explorer 11  popup blocker is enabled or not?
I am using the below code to detect pop up blocker. It works fine in  chrome but not in **Internetnternet explorer 11**

```
var newWindow = open('/', 'example', 'width=300,height=300')
if (newWindow===null || typeof(newWindow)==="undefined" || newWindow === false || newWindow ==="" || newWindow===0) {
    alert("popup  blocker enabled");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed it for you this time, but when you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Always best to make sure your question is clear and easy to read. :-)

Comment: Side note: That `if` with the massive `||` can be replaced with simply: `if (!newWindow)`. That checks if `newWindow` is a falsy value. Your `||` version explicitly checks for all falsy values except `NaN`, but `newWindow` will either be an object reference or `null`, never one of the other falsy values, so it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I can think of is to have the window you're opening as a test call back to the main window via its `opener` property. The page you're popping up would have this script code in it:

```
if (opener) {
    opener.poppedUp();
}
```

Your detection code would be along these lines:

```
function openWithPopupDetection(options) {
    var newWindow = open(options.url, options.name, options.features);
    if (!newWindow) {
        // Chrome and similar, it didn't pop up
        setTimeout(options.callback, 0, false);
    } else {
        var popTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            // Give up on the popup...
            window.poppedUp = null;
            options.callback(false);
        }, AnAppropriateNumberOfMilliseconds);
        window.poppedUp = function() {
            // Popped up, clear the timer
            clearTimeout(popTimer);
            window.poppedUp = null;
            options.callback(true);
        };
    }
}
```

then you'd use it like this:

```
openWithPopupDetection({
    url: 'page.html',
    name: 'example',
    features: 'width=300,height=300',
    callback: function(flag) {
        if (!flag) {
            alert(/*...*/);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the detection will, of necessity, be asynchronous. Since it will be asynchronous sometimes, note that the above makes it asynchronous all the time.

(If you may have more than one call to the above that overlap, you'll need to do some management around the name of the `poppedUp` function, probably generating the name each time and passing it as a query parameter.)

Comment: Thanks , your solution  worked on CHrome and Opera but not on IE 11. pls help

Comment: @kondrap - That doesn't give me any information to work with. What aspect didn't work? What error messages did you get? What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: @kondrap - Works perfectly for me (including in IE11): http://output.jsbin.com/kiratowula